# Create a new col and fill it within groups and conditions in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Hel lo I have a df such as :

```
Groups COL1
G1 AB 
G1 CD
G1 EF
G1 EF
G2 CD
G2 CD
G3 CD
G3 EF
G3 EF
G4 EF
G4 AB
G4 AB
G5 EF
G5 EF
```

and I would like to create a new column for each Groups where I add the same values `AB`, `CD` or `EF`.

Where if there is at least one `AB`, all have `AB`, 
if there is no `AB` but at least on `CD`, all have `CD` and 
if there is only `EF`, all have `CF`.

so basicaly:

```
AB>CD>EF
```

here I should get :

```
Groups COL1 NewCOL
G1 AB AB
G1 CD AB
G1 EF AB
G1 EF AB
G2 CD CD
G2 CD CD
G3 CD CD
G3 EF CD
G3 EF CD
G4 EF AB
G4 AB AB
G4 AB AB
G5 EF EF
G5 EF EF
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: What did you try? Which error/output did you get?

Comment: I know how to use groupby `df['newCOL'] = df.groupby(['Groups'])`but I do not know how to add the fact that I want to add AB, CD or EF depending on the COL1 containt

Comment: I guess this is a simplified example. In the application, how is the priority of the entries given, i.e. Lexicographically, by some custom list or in some other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use, [`DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) on `COL1` along with [`np.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

```
df['NewCol'] = (
    df.groupby('Groups')['COL1']
    .transform(
        lambda s: np.select(
            [s.eq('AB').any(), s.eq('CD').any(), s.eq('EF').any()], ['AB', 'CD', 'EF']))
)
```

---

```
# print(df)
   Groups COL1 NewCol
0      G1   AB     AB
1      G1   CD     AB
2      G1   EF     AB
3      G1   EF     AB
4      G2   CD     CD
5      G2   CD     CD
6      G3   CD     CD
7      G3   EF     CD
8      G3   EF     CD
9      G4   EF     AB
10     G4   AB     AB
11     G4   AB     AB
12     G5   EF     EF
13     G5   EF     EF
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution, using `pandas.Categorical`:

```
df['COL1'] =  pd.Categorical(df['COL1'], ['AB', 'CD', 'EF'], ordered=True)
df['NewCol'] = df.groupby('Groups')['COL1'].transform('min')
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   Groups COL1 NewCol
0      G1   AB     AB
1      G1   CD     AB
2      G1   EF     AB
3      G1   EF     AB
4      G2   CD     CD
5      G2   CD     CD
6      G3   CD     CD
7      G3   EF     CD
8      G3   EF     CD
9      G4   EF     AB
10     G4   AB     AB
11     G4   AB     AB
12     G5   EF     EF
13     G5   EF     EF
```